# How do I update a LottieCompose clipSpec at runtime

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I have a Lottie animation that I want to start then when it gets to a certain frame I want to loop from frame X to frame Y.

The issue I am running up against is that I cant seem to figure out how to update the `clipSpec` at runtime with `LottieCompose` as `clipSpec` cannot be reassigned.

I was able to do this no problem with normal XML layout based Lottie like this

```kotlin
loading_animation.addAnimatorUpdateListener {

    if(initialLoad && loading_animation.frame == 15){
        initialLoad = false
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        loading_animation.setMinAndMaxFrame(15,28)
    }

    if(!initialLoad && authenticated && System.currentTimeMillis() >= (startTime+1000)){
        loading_animation.pauseAnimation()
        startActivity()
    }

}
```

here is my `LottieCompose` code I have so far

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.sun_icon))
val animatable = rememberLottieAnimatable()
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition, iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever)
LottieAnimation(composition = composition, progress = progress, modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clipSpec` can be specified with `animateLottieCompositionAsState`. You can update it just like any other state in Compose: create a state variable and update it with some action/side-effect.

Learn more about state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI), which explains the basic principles.

`getFrameForProgress` returns a frame in `Float`, I am not sure if it is safe to convert it to `Int` and compare equals (is it guaranteed that every frame is rendered? on slow devices it might not be), so my comparison code looks not too nice.

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw. sun_icon))
var clipSpec by remember { mutableStateOf<LottieClipSpec?>(null)}
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition,
    clipSpec = clipSpec,
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
)
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = progress,
    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
)
var initialLoad by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
if (initialLoad && composition?.getFrameForProgress(progress)?.let { it >= 15f } == true) {
    SideEffect {
        initialLoad = false
        clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Frame(
            min = 15,
            max = 28
        )
    }
}
```